Wpf problem: textbox with style won't get value inside textbox. (It always be empty string)
I am new in wpf programming. When I click the button. It should show me the message inside the textbox. However, It shows only an empty string. My textbox is using a custom style named "ModernTextBox".
This is my xaml textbox
<TextBox Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="1" Height="50"
         VerticalAlignment="Center" Style="{StaticResource ModernTextBox}" x:Name="NameInsertTextBox"  
         />
<Button Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="2" x:Name="NameInsertButton" VerticalAlignment="Stretch"
        Background="{StaticResource LightColorBrush}" Content="Insert" FontSize="12" Foreground= "White" BorderThickness="0"
        Click="NameInsertButton_Click"></Button>

This is my ModernTextBox Style
<ResourceDictionary xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
                    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml">
    <Style TargetType="{x:Type TextBox}" x:Key="ModernTextBox">
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type TextBox}">
                    <Border CornerRadius="10"
                            Background="AliceBlue"
                            >
                        <Grid>
                            <Rectangle StrokeThickness="1">
                                
                            </Rectangle>
                            <TextBox Margin="1" Text="{TemplateBinding Text}" BorderThickness="0" Background="Transparent"
                                     VerticalContentAlignment="Center" Padding="5" Foreground="{StaticResource AccentGreyColorBrush}" x:Name="SearchBox">
                            </TextBox>
                            <TextBlock IsHitTestVisible="False" Text="Input seperated with commas" VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Left"
                                       Margin="10,0,0,0" FontSize="11" Foreground="DarkGray" Grid.Column="1">
                                <TextBlock.Style>
                                    <Style TargetType="{x:Type TextBlock}">
                                        <Style.Triggers>
                                            <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Text, ElementName=SearchBox}" Value="">
                                                <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="Visible">

                                                </Setter>
                                            </DataTrigger>
                                        </Style.Triggers>
                                        <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="Hidden">
                                        </Setter>
                                    </Style>
                                </TextBlock.Style>
                                
                            </TextBlock>
                        </Grid>
                    </Border>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
        
    </Style>
</ResourceDictionary>


And finally, this is my code inside
private void NameInsertButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
 
    MessageBox.Show(NameInsertTextBox.Text);
    //sqlButton(nameInsertTextBox, NameInsertTextBox, "Insert");

}

It seems like the problem lies on
<TextBox Margin="1" Text="{TemplateBinding Text}" BorderThickness="0" Background="Transparent"
         VerticalContentAlignment="Center" Padding="5" Foreground="{StaticResource AccentGreyColorBrush}" x:Name="SearchBox">
</TextBox>

in moderntextbox. But I still can't find a way to fix it.

One obvious mistake is you have a text box in the template. Don't.

Some controls have mandatory template parts if you want it to function properly. You can check Control Styles and Templates to get the named parts of the individual control.

The TextBox has a PART_ContentHost named element, which the TextBox uses to  render the content. Just replace the TextBox with the named part. The original content host is a ScrollViewer . See TextBox Styles and Templates to know the template parts and to see an example COntrolTemplate for the TextBox.

You can always add the original control to your XAML and then right click it in the XAML designer and select "Edit template/Edit a copy". This will create the current style with the template that you can edit.

just Change:
<TextBox Text="{TemplateBinding Text}"

To:
<TextBox Text="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}, Path=Text}"

